# How to replace a td with elements with empty td

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i have a structure like

```
<td valign="top" style="width:150px;" > 
     <img alt="<recipetitle/>" src="http://<rootweburl/>/photos/recipes/Large/<recipephotoname/>" alt="logo" style="float:left;"/> 
</td>
```

Where `<recipetitle/>` and `<recipephotoname/>`  are parameters and can change .I want to replace this td with a empty td .How will i do that in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your table cell a server side control so you can access it from code behind.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width:150px;" runat="server" id="tdToBeCleared">
            <img alt="<recipetitle/>" src="http://<rootweburl/>/photos/recipes/Large/<recipephotoname/>" alt="logo" style="float:left;"/>  
        </td>         
    </tr>
</table>
```

In codebehind, you can change the innerhtml of your control. If you want to clear the content, simply use the following line:

```
tdToBeCleared.InnerHtml = string.Empty;
```

---

***Edit:*** Just changed the td to match with your example, you can simply copy and paste.

Comment: Alternative - make the image a server control the same way and manipulate it's `Visible` property.